# retrieve all values in a loop

Tags: custom-field

I thought I'd found an alternative to a problem, but I've just realized that I can't retrieve all the checkbox values.
DEBUG

```
array(1) {
  ["row0"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["field110"]=>
    string(3) "119"
    ["field112"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(12) "réalisation"
      [1]=>
      string(16) "édition DVD ..."
    }
  }
}
string(12) "réalisation"
Kamea Meah( réalisation )
```

I can retrieve the 1st value out of 4, but not the 2nd.
See the current code, which should work in php > 8.2

CODE

```
if ('films-pros' === $field->name && 'subform' === $field->type) { 
        echo "<br /><b><span><i class='fa fa-link fa-1x' aria-hidden='true'></i></span> Pro(s) en lien avec ce film : </b>"; 
        $field_value = json_decode($this->item->jcfields[111]->rawvalue, true);
        echo '<pre>', var_dump($field_value), '</pre>'; // ok   
        $app = Factory::getApplication();
        $factory = $app->bootComponent('com_content')->getMVCFactory();    
        $table = $factory->createTable('Article', 'Table');         
 
        foreach ($field->subform_rows as $subform_row) {
            foreach ($subform_row as $subField) {    
                if ('film-pro-lie' === $subField->fieldname) 
            {
                        $titre_art = $subField->value;
                $article_id = $field_value['row0']['field110']; 
                $table->load($article_id); /* obligé de mettre ces 2 lignes ici */  
                $item_catid = $table->catid;
                //echo '<pre>', var_dump($article_id), '</pre>';$field_value['row0']['field112']; Nu ide
 
                $film_type_pro = $field_value['row0']['field112'][0];               
                echo '<pre>', var_dump($film_type_pro), '</pre>';                       
                        echo HTMLHelper::link(
                        Route::link("site", "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id={$article_id}&catid={$item_catid}"),
                        $titre_art  ."( " .$film_type_pro ." )");                   
 
                }
 
            }
 
 
 
 
        }
 
        }
```